# Do AIR applications run in a trusted sandbox?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, sockets, air

I have an AIR application that is packaged with a network appliance and that is used to configure that network appliance...much like a the embedded webservers on home routers except this is an installed AIR app.

If I want to communicate with the appliance on a port higher that 1024, do I need that appliance to serve up a socket policy file or is AIR considered a trusted sandbox. All the info I find relates to Flash Player and the web, but this particular AIR app is communicating in a closed environment.

Answer (score 1):

From: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AIR/1.5/devappsflex/devappsflex.pdf

There's a whole chapter on AIR and Sandboxes, starting at page 75

> AIR provides a comprehensive security architecture that defines permissions accordingly to each file in an AIR 
>   application, both internal and external. Permissions are granted to files according to their origin, and are assigned into 
>   logical security groupings called sandboxes.